# How to keep asking for a valid input in python without stopping the code

Tags: python, loops, input, try-except

Hi I am trying to have my code ask for an input until the correct value had been entered. if the input is correct then it proceeds to perform other tasks. Otherwise the user is to be prompted again. I tried using Try/Except but cannot get it right. I have this:

```
while True:
try:
    radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
    if radius > 1 and radius < 0:
        
        break
        print("Radius must be between 0 and 1. Try again: \n")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    print( 'ok lets go on')
    ### more tasks are performed and stuff ###
```

In order to continue the user must input a float radius between 0 and 1. otherwise it keeps asking. Im still new so thanks for your patience!

Comment: There are several things wrong here.. to start with how can the radius be great than 1 AND less that 0?

Comment: Thats the thing, if they input a value outside of 0 and 1 then they have to try again. If they input smaller than 1 and larger than 0 then the code continues. Maybe I should have used 'or' ?

Comment: Read my answer, it's or.  If the value is over 1 OR if it's less than 0.  It cannot be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong. It's not possible for a number to be both `<0` and `>1`,  `finally` will always be run regardless of the result of the `try` and `except` blocks, you are not breaking out of the `while` loop so end up running forever.

Something like this would do it:

```
while True:
    try:
        radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
        if radius > 1 or radius < 0:
            print("Radius must be between 0 and 1. Try again: \n")
        else:
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

print( 'ok lets go on')
```

Comment: Thank you! I see I was trying to make it harder than it needed to be.

Comment: Mark as correct if the answer has solved your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    try:
        radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
        if radius < 1.0 and radius > 0.0:
            break
            print("Radius must be between 0 and 1. Try again: \n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('ok lets go on')
        ### more tasks are performed and stuff ###
```

It will be working good
just correct the operators

before

```
  if radius > 1 and radius < 0 :
```

after

```
 if radius < 1.0 and radius > 0.0:
```

output

```
Enter radius: 0.9
ok lets go on

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: There is no loop to break out of.  This will not work.

Comment: /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/hussein/PycharmProjects/TestPython/venv/sr/test3.py
Enter radius: 0.9
ok lets go on

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Where is the loop to break out of in your code?

Comment: this "if radius < 1.0 and radius > 0.0:
            break"

Comment: when the logic  is true

Comment: radius < 1.0 
0.9 is < 1.0 = true
0.9 is >0.0 = true 
true and true = true

Comment: You can copy it and testing it by your ida

Comment: An if statement is not a loop. Your code has no loop in it. You’re not breaking out of a loop. You've either not tested it or you've copied and pasted incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

> your iterations and if conditions are wrong. between 0 to 1 mean we
> cant get 0 as input we must reject it. and we must reject invalid
> inputs like strings

```
radius = float()
    while True:
        try:
            radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
            if ((radius >= 1) or (radius <= 0)):
                print("Radius must be between 0 and 1. Try again: \n")
                continue
            else:
                break
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Float required !")
            print(ex)
            
    
    print("radius" +  str(radius))
```

Answer (score 0):

There're several problems in the code.

First, there's an indentation: the code to be repeated in the cycle should be additionally indented (one level deeper then the `while` keyword.

Second, the condition you check is incorrect: there should rather be `or` operator:

```
if radius > 1 and radius < 0:
```

*(this condition is never satisfied as the value can't be less then 0 and grater than 1 simultaneously).*

Third, you should better decide when to exit the cycle. You can do it explicitly by using `break` keyword after yiou check that the value is correct. In you current code you are trying to do it if the value doesn't meet your [incorrect] condition.

In case you need to immediately start the next loop, use the `continue` keyword.

And also I can't see why you need the `finally` block there.

So the code should look smth. like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
        if radius > 1 or radius < 0:
            print("Radius must be between 0 and 1. Try again: \n")
            continue 
            
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue

print( 'ok lets go on')
### more tasks are performed and stuff ###
```

The last `continue` keyword is not necessary in this case as the cycle will repeat automatically after the last statement, but I've left it there for the code readability.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the details.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
    if radius > 1 or radius < 0:
        print("Radius must be between 0 and 1. Try again: \n")
        continue
    else:
        print('ok lets go on')
```

It does what you say. But please let me know in the comments when you want to break the code.

Comment: What if someone types in Rishabh as their radius?